# How to use a switch (clickCount) function to change multiple images then change url

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, click-counting

I'm trying to find a way to change an image multiple times, then navigate to a new url; all by clicking the same button. I've been playing around with a switch (clickCount) function, which seems to be the best solution from what other people have suggested and from what I've read elsewhere.

However, I've never used either a switch or clickCount before and I can't get the code to work despite reading/watching several tutorials. But I have no idea why (I'm pretty sure it's something very obvious that my limited knowledge is failing to spot) and I've been stuck on this issue for a week now, so nothing is making sense any more!

The code I have so far...

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" div class="toshow">
    <img src="infoscreenarrows.jpg" alt="Title" />
    <img src="infoscreentext.png" id="infoscreentext" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="enterbutton">
    <input type=image id=multiclick img src="silvercogarrow.png" alt="Enter" >
</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var clickCount = 0;

function clickHandler () {
    clickCount += 1;
    switch (clickCount) {
    case 1:
        var image = document.getElementById("infoscreentext");
        image.src="infoscreentext2.png";
        // 1st click on SilverCogArrow changes image infoscreentext to infoscreentext2
    break;
    case 2:
        var image = document.getElementById("infoscreentext");
        image.src="infoscreentext3.png";
        // 2nd click on SilverCogArrow changes image infoscreentext2 to infoscreentext3
    break;
    case 3:
        window.location.href = "castleview.html";
        // 3rd click on SilverCogArrow changes page to castleview.html
break;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. input type=image is a submit button
2. you are not attaching clickHandler to the button

Try

```
<button type="button" onclick="clickHandler()"><img 
src="silvercogarrow.png" alt="Enter" /></button>
```

Comment: I love you! You can take my firstborn child!